# How to use a vector image (.svg) with best quality in another format for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, svg, vector-graphics

I have a [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) .svg to create a image for iPhone. I know I can't use a .svg directly to iPhone because cocoa touch don't render it (maybe with others libs).

So, I have to convert the image for a format to use in iPhone. So, what is the best format to have the best quality in iPhone? I will create image for Retina (2x) and for normal.

Is it .png the best choice? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PNG is definitely the best choice as it's the de-facto standard on iOS. The SDK processes PNGs in build phase and they can be loaded into memory directly. So they're super fast. You need to have normal PNGs and @2x to support retina display.

Answer (score 2):

Rendering vector-based graphics usually costs much resources (just as writing codes to draw with the Core Graphics API). On a mobile device, using raster graphics balances the performance and the quality. I think there's less cases in which we want to scale the UI elements to any level.

Creating 2 sets of design elements do cost you more time, but it's acceptable. With batch processing, you can save some time. Be sure to check each graphic on the real devices and manually refine it for better looking.